# How to find out a tab bar controller inside a SlideMenuController swift?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, rootviewcontroller

I have implemented an EXSlideMenuController and added a TabBarController as a main view controller in the sliding menu controller but now I want to find out the first view controller of TabBarController which is inside the EXSlideMenuController.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let menuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuViewController") as! MenuViewController
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarControllerID") as! TabBarController
let revealController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController: initialViewController, leftMenuViewController: menuViewController)
self.window?.rootViewController = revealController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

how do I find out the first view controller of tab bar controller from the ExSlideMenuController?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to find out the first view controller of a tab bar controller inside an ExSlideMenuController

```
let rootController = self.window?.rootViewController as! ExSlideMenuController
let customTabBarController = rootController.mainViewController as! CustomTabBarController
let navBarController = customTabBarController.viewControllers?.first as! UINavigationController
let storeController = navBarController.viewControllers.first as! StoreListViewController
```

may be it will help some other person.